# Grouping by rows based on time interval in bigquery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table as below with per minute ('`time`' column) records for multiple user and for different dates. I have created another column (`time_3min`) for 3 minute interval. Now I want to group by rows based on `time_3min` column and sum up the '`value`' column.

```
userId  date            time            time_3min   value
abc 2023-04-10  01:00:00    01:00:00    2
abc 2023-04-10  01:01:00    01:00:00    5
abc 2023-04-10  01:02:00    01:00:00    3
abc 2023-04-10  01:03:00    01:03:00    6
abc 2023-04-10  01:04:00    01:03:00    7
abc 2023-04-10  01:05:00    01:03:00    1
abc 2023-04-11  01:00:00    01:00:00    10
abc 2023-04-11  01:01:00    01:00:00    5
abc 2023-04-11  01:02:00    01:00:00    3
abc 2023-04-11  01:03:00    01:03:00    7
abc 2023-04-11  01:04:00    01:03:00    4
abc 2023-04-11  01:05:00    01:03:00    3
xyz 2023-04-10  01:00:00    01:00:00    11
xyz 2023-04-10  01:01:00    01:00:00    8
xyz 2023-04-10  01:02:00    01:00:00    6
xyz 2023-04-10  01:03:00    01:03:00    4
xyz 2023-04-10  01:04:00    01:03:00    6
xyz 2023-04-10  01:05:00    01:03:00    2
xyz 2023-04-11  01:00:00    01:00:00    11
xyz 2023-04-11  01:01:00    01:00:00    8
xyz 2023-04-11  01:02:00    01:00:00    7
xyz 2023-04-11  01:03:00    01:03:00    4
xyz 2023-04-11  01:04:00    01:03:00    6
xyz 2023-04-11  01:05:00    01:03:00    6
```

I want to display the data as below

```
userId  date            time_3min   sum(value)
abc 2023-04-10  01:00:00    10
abc 2023-04-10  01:03:00    14
abc 2023-04-11  01:00:00    18
abc 2023-04-11  01:03:00    14
xyz 2023-04-10  01:00:00    25
xyz 2023-04-10  01:03:00    12
xyz 2023-04-11  01:00:00    26
xyz 2023-04-11  01:03:00    16
```

Could you please suggest how to use right group by clause to calculate `sum` with `order by` based on `date` and `time_3min`

`group by` and `order by` in bigquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be just:

```
 WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'abc' as userId, '2023-04-10' as date, '01:00:00' as time, '01:00:00' as time_3min, 2 as value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-10', '01:01:00', '01:00:00', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-10', '01:02:00', '01:00:00', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-10', '01:03:00', '01:03:00', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-10', '01:04:00', '01:03:00', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-10', '01:05:00', '01:03:00', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-11', '01:00:00', '01:00:00', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-11', '01:01:00', '01:00:00', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-11', '01:02:00', '01:00:00', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-11', '01:03:00', '01:03:00', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-11', '01:04:00', '01:03:00', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2023-04-11', '01:05:00', '01:03:00', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-10', '01:00:00', '01:00:00', 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-10', '01:01:00', '01:00:00', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-10', '01:02:00', '01:00:00', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-10', '01:03:00', '01:03:00', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-10', '01:04:00', '01:03:00', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-10', '01:05:00', '01:03:00', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-11', '01:00:00', '01:00:00', 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-11', '01:01:00', '01:00:00', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-11', '01:02:00', '01:00:00', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-11', '01:03:00', '01:03:00', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-11', '01:04:00', '01:03:00', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', '2023-04-11', '01:05:00', '01:03:00', 6 
)
SELECT userID
       ,date
      ,time_3min
      ,SUM(value)
FROM data
GROUP BY userID
        ,date
        ,time_3min
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @gotqn. I am using the same group by clause as you have suggested in my environment but I am not getting all rows for different interval for the same date first. I am getting as below. I want to see (23:45:00, 23:30:00, 23:15:00, 23:00:00) these 4 (15 min) intervals rows for the same date '2023-03-16' and its respective sum(value)  
userId date                  time_15min sum(value)
abc         2023-03-16 23:45:00         32
abc         2023-03-17 23:45:00          46
abc         2023-03-18 23:45:00          73

Comment: Can't you run my query - it is based on your input data?

Comment: Your query is working perfect, that's the sample data I gave you. Not sure why in my  environment its not displaying result in same fashion.

Comment: @Awssylearn One reason can be the column types. Could you try adding some more data in order to break it?